# Is there any construction of real numbers that does not use a quotient space in the process?

Tags: analysis, order-theory, real-numbers

I am working on an isomorphism (in terms of order and operations) from the power set of integers to R. I would like to know if anyone knows of any construction of the real numbers that uses such a simple set to provide it with the structure of the real number system. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite follow what is your question, but perhaps continued fractions have something to do with it.

Comment: Google "Dedekind Cuts"

Comment: In using the rational numbers we are using elements of a quotient space. Namely, Q itself is a quotient space.

Answer (score 5):

*If we take the rationals as given* (or construct them without using a quotient procedure - see my comment below), then the **Dedekind cut** construction, I think, does what you want.

A real number, the idea goes,$^*$ is completely characterized by the way it "cuts" the number line into two pieces. This cut is completely determined by which rationals wind up on which side, and conversely every "reasonable" partition of the rationals corresponds to a real number (this is the *completeness* of the reals). This motivates the following definition:

> A *Dedekind cut* is a pair $(A, B)$ of nonempty sets of rationals such that every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$, $A$ has no greatest element, and $A\cup B=\mathbb{Q}$.

The intuition here is that $(A, B$) is the unique real number "between" $A$ and $B$. E.g. the cut $(A_\pi, B_\pi)$ corresponding to $\pi$ has $3, 3.1, 3.14, ...\in A_\pi$ and $4, 3.2, 3.15, ...\in B_\pi$.

The asymmetry between $A$ and $B$ - where $A$ must have no greatest element, but $B$ is allowed to have a least element - is to accommodate the rationals. The cut corresponding to ${1\over 2}$ needs to put ${1\over 2}$ on one side or the other; we've arbitrarily decided that in this situation we'll put ${1\over 2}$ on the right (the $B$-side).

There is no need to take equivalence classes in this approach: given any real number $r$, there is a **unique** Dedekind cut corresponding to it, namely $$Cut_r=(\{p\in\mathbb{Q}: p<r\},\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: q\ge r\}).$$ The basic arithmetic structure on the reals "ports over" without serious difficulty; for example, the ordering is given by $$(A_1, B_1)\le (A_2, B_2)\iff A_1\subseteq A_2.$$ That said, the Cauchy sequence construction of the reals allows a much easier development of arithmetic; my point here is just that no *serious* difficulty crops up with cuts.

---

Note that the notion of a Dedekind cut, while geometrically pleasing, is somewhat redundant. We could also just work with the "right side" of a cut:

> A *half-cut* (this is not standard terminology) $C$ is a nonempty upwards-closed proper subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

The idea is that the real associated to $C$ is its *greatest lower bound*.

---

$^*$Personally, I think Dedekind's original essay does a wonderful job of motivating the idea, and it's still my favorite construction of the reals. The construction of the reals as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences has lots of advantages over it - in particular, defining the basic arithmetic operations is easier with them than with cuts - but I really find Dedekind cuts to have lots of aesthetic value. And down the road, they wind up being quite important and useful in logic.

Comment: This is not hte case, because if we use the rational numbers, we are indeed using a quotiente space *in the process* because Q is a quotient space when constructed from Z, which also is a quotient space. So, implicitly, we are using them.

Comment: @JuanRamirez Actually, you can construct the rationals without using a quotient operation at all, the point being that every rational has a canonical form (namely, put numerator and denominator in lowest terms). But that's a fair point; I've edited to clarify.

Comment: In fact, canonical Cauchy sequences for reals also exist: namely, have the $n$th term get the $n$th significant digit correctly. So the canonical Cauchy sequence corresponding to $100+\pi$ is $$(100, 100, 103, 103.1, 103.14, 103.141, ...).$$

Comment: @JuanRamirez Incidentally, I think you should specify in your question that you also don't want to start with $\mathbb{Q}$. Most of the time (although [there are exceptions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405454.pdf)), when we speak of "constructing the reals" we mean "constructing the reals *from the rationals*," hence my carefree use of them.

Comment: Yes, I tried to clarify that the intention is to equip $2^\mathbb Z$ with the structure of the real numbers.

Comment: I am familiar with these other constructions but I am looking for one that is defined on subsets of the integers.

Comment: @JuanRamirez It might be worth actually making an edit to the question to reflect that, then. The phrase "such a simple set" doesn't suggest that you care about $2^\mathbb{Z}$ specifically, and my answer stemmed from the fact that I consider the set of nonempty proper upwards-closed sets of rationals to be a similarly simple set. For what it's worth, we can cook up a perfectly constructive bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $2^\mathbb{Z}$ and use this to give $2^\mathbb{Z}$ the appropriate structure without taking any quotients, but that's a bit artificial.

Comment: There is meanwhile a topological obstacle to a too-nice construction. Since $2^\mathbb{Z}$ (with the usual topology) isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology), any way we construct $\mathbb{R}$ from $2^\mathbb{Z}$ has to be either "non-injective" (= quotient construction), "non-total" (= some sets of integers don't correspond to reals), or discontinuous (= along the lines of the artificial construction I mentioned in my previous comment). And finally, as noted above, there's the point that we can construct $\mathbb{Q}$ without quotient operations. (cont'd)

Comment: In fact, the "lowest terms" construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ is arguably pretty natural, since we intuitively think of e.g. ${1\over 2}$ as the "right" name for the rational whose double is the multiplicative unit - as opposed to ${2\over 4}$, ${3\over 6}$, etc.

Comment: There is in fact, a subspace of $2^\mathbb Z$, that satisfies an isomorphism for order, sum and product into the positive real numbers.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800872/describe-an-infinite-process-of-denumerable-steps-that-defines-supremum-propert

Comment: @JuanRamirez Yes, that's referred to in my second option - ""non-total" (= some sets of integers don't correspond to reals)." EDIT: Although I don't quite understand the specific example in the linked question; note that the set of bounded sets of naturals is **countable** ...

Comment: @JuanRamirez If you're comfortable looking at a subset of $2^\mathbb{Z}$ or similar, just do the following. First, look at $2^\mathbb{N}$ instead of $2^\mathbb{Z}$. Next, let $X$ be the set of non-empty co-infinite elements of $2^\mathbb{N}$. Now we have a simple bijection between $X$ and $(0,1)$ - view an element of $X$ as a non-trailing-$1$s binary expansion of an element of $(0, 1)$. Finally, fix your favorite nice homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and you're done. You can do a similar trick to use [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) instead.

Comment: Your explanation is succinct, elegant, and informative! :-)