# Describe an infinite process of denumerable steps, that defines supremum property for the following set X (supremum of any bounded subset of X exists)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, lattice-orders, ordered-fields

Let $X\subset 2^{\mathbb Z}$ be the set that consists of subsets of $\mathbb Z$ that are bounded above. That is to say, $A\in X$ iff $A\subset\mathbb Z$ and $\exists\max A$. Show that the set $X$ has the property of Supremum; namely, that there is a least upper bound for any bounded set, of bounded above subsets of $
\mathbb Z$. The idea is to provide an explicit construction of the supremum, in at most infinite denumerable steps for any case. Of course, the first step is to define a proper order which is already worked out. The order is as follows: Let $A,B\in X$ two different sets, which makes the symmetric difference non empty. We say $A<B$ iff $\max A\triangle B\in B$. Otherwise, if $\max A\triangle B\in A$ we say $A>B$. It is not too difficult to prove this is a linear order and that every two elements are comparable. So with this, we try to build the supremum of $X$. Why? Because this set is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ in terms of order, and an explicit isomorphism can be given using the binary expansion of real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's restrict attention to nonempty sets of integers, for simplicity. (Also, because $\emptyset$ is minimal according to your ordering, which I don't think you want.)

*For clarity I'll write "$\triangleleft$" for your ordering to distinguish it from the usual ordering $<$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.*

If $A\subseteq X$ is nonempty and $\triangleleft$-bounded above, then it does indeed have a supremum, as follows. The key observation is that a $\triangleleft$-bounded set has a maximum integer occurring in any of its elements.

- Let $z_0=\max(\bigcup A)$ and let $A_0=\{B\in A: z_0\in B\}$.
- Having defined $z_i$ and $A_i$, let $z_{i+1}=\max((\bigcup A_i)\setminus\{z_i\})$ if it exists, and $z_{i+1}=z_i$ otherwise, and let $A_{i+1}=\{B\in A_i: z_{i+1}\in B\}.$

It's not hard to show that $\sup(A)=\{z_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

That said, it's not yet obvious to me that in fact you get something order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. The supremum property alone doesn't characterize $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordering (think about an arbitrary ordinal). EDIT: In fact, unless I'm missing something they're *not* order-isomorphic: there is nothing strictly $\triangleleft$-between $\{..., -3,-2,-1\}$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: So right, I made a mistake in typing $2^\mathbb N$, its actually $2^\mathbb Z$. subsets of $\mathbb Z$ that are bounded above (not below).

Comment: Perfectly put. The way in which we make this isomorphic to the positive real numbers is using the binary expansion of a number. That is to say, any number $x\in\mathbb R^+$ is expressable as a sum of integer powers of 2, so that $x=\sum_{i\in A}2^i$ for some set $A\in X$.

Comment: We can give the algebraic structure of the reals, using set operations. That is, we can prove that $X$ is exactly the system of real numbers because we can show it is a totally ordered field with the supremum property.

Comment: @JuanRamirez Um, unless I'm missing something $\{0\}$ and $\{..., -3,-2,-1\}$ both correspond to $1$ under that map. So you still need to take a quotient, or "thin" your set even more (and this gets to the points I made in my comments to your other question).

Comment: Under our definition of order $\{0\}$ is greater. Its only until we define our operation that we can say they are the same, as a result of the definition of operation, which is posed in the next question.          https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801017/prove-associativity-for-the-following-space?noredirect=1#comment5774921_2801017

Comment: Yes, there are repeated elements. The equality of these is equivalent to saying $\sum_{i<n}2^i=2^n$.

Comment: @JuanRamirez Well, that corresponds to a quotient operation: you're constructing the reals as a quotient of $X$.

Comment: yeah, true. but its the simplest quotient ive seen.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions. they provided alot of insight.

Comment: @JuanRamirez Well, you can avoid quotients entirely via the quotient-free construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ I described above, plus Dedekind cuts. But yes - what you've described is equivalent to usual base-2 notation for reals, and indeed the only quotienting you need to do is to fix the dyadic rationals.

Comment: Yes, we are using base two, but we are not working with sequences. In fact the algorithms that can be defined in this space are very straightforward for everything from calculating supremum to calulating roots and rational powers. The reason I think this becomes more natural is that we work with the simplest set that has the cardinality of the continuum. Also, we get the structure $[0,1]$ as a generalization of the structure of $\mathbb N$ (we make the natural numbers iso to the set of bounded sets of N, and we make all the subsets of N iso to the continuum [0,1]).

Comment: @JuanRamirez You are working with things equivalent to sequences. Given a bounded set of integers, take the characteristic function, flip it and put a decimal point after the $0$; this gives you the corresponding sequence. This really is just binary expansions, phrased slightly obliquely.

Comment: It seems to me it provides some insight to the real numbers, and it also differs from other constructions of the real numbers in that it provides the real structure to a set that is significantly simpler than any other set that has been found to be isomorphic to $R$. Actually it provides a construction of the real numbers in terms of the simplest possible set with the cardinality of the continuum. In a sense it seems to be a minimized construction if we talk about the logical order of the objects in use.

Comment: Perhaps you have not properly analyzed the algorithms for operation and order we have proposed, or other constructions of the reals, so as to appreciate the advantages of this construction.